# Qt Creator - No QML utility installed

Tags: macos, qt, qml, qt5, vcpkg

I'm trying to install Qt from vcpkg.

On macOS Monterey, while trying to add Qt installation from vcpkg on QtCreator it seems to complain about:

```
No QML utility installed.
```

And perhaps `QT_SYSROOT` is missing?

How should I proceed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

And trying to build a simple Qt project will led to:

[image]

Comment: Did you install the whole package on the Qt Installer ? Maybe you miss QtQuick which use qml. Could you re launch your installer ?

Comment: I installed only QtCreator using Qt Installer.

Comment: Ok, have you seen that you had to select some packages under the Qt version (during installation) ? Did you select one of them ?

Comment: Sorry, where? During installation on vcpkg? I installed with `vcpkg install qt5`, which takes a long time and seems to install everything (almost)

Comment: Ok, go to your Qt installation folder. then launch MaintenanceTool. Select add or remove component. Then go under Qt, select your version and select the whole checkboxs (just in case). You could go in "developper and designers tools " too and select -> Qt Design Studio, CMake, Conan and Ninja

Comment: You could try this too , under Tools > External > Qt Quick > configure. then QML utility. 
and change the path for  %{CurrentDocument:Project:QT_INSTALL_BINS}\qml}

Comment: About your previous comment, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want to install it using vcpkg instead. Somethings cannot be installed with vcpkg (i.e. QtCreator), that ones I'll install another way (i.e. using the MaintenanceTool)

Comment: I think you need to install at least one set of prebuilt binaries... based on your comment that you only installed qtcreator

Comment: What is `prebuild binaries`?